# How does your heart heal

Tags: heart, recovery, self-healing-repairing

My understanding is that muscles heal primarily while resting. When you lift heavy things you cause small tears in the muscle then while resting and heal back stronger (I'm assuming that's how it works).

Your heart however doesn't get a rest day though, it keeps beating at 50-60 bpm ever minute of every day barring accidents and death. After a strenuous cardio workout (10 mile run for time) it doesnt get a typical "rest" day. So does it "heal" in the same manner as other muscles, or is there a different mechanism that it uses to recuperate after being strained?